Facetting the survival plot using ggsurvplot_facet gives error
I am analyzing EHR data of diabetic patients. The objective is to perform time-to-event analyses to explore whether switching therapies at certain HbA1c thresholds leads to better long-term outcomes, specifically whether different therapy groups show differences in the development of diabetes complications. The event of interest is diabetic complications. I am trying to create plots for the various therapies, faceted by HbA1c thresholds. Below is the code with dummy data, but it gives an error. Can someone please help
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)
library(survminer)
library(survival)
set.seed(42)
data <- data.frame(
  PatientID = 1:100,
  SwitchType = sample(c("A to B", "B to C", "C to D"), 100, replace = TRUE),
  HbA1c = sample(c("<=7%", "7-8%", ">8%"), 100, replace = TRUE),
  SwitchDate = as.Date("2022-01-01") + sample(0:500, 100, replace = TRUE),
  EventDate = as.Date("2022-01-01") + sample(300:800, 100, replace = TRUE),
  CensorDate = as.Date("2023-01-01") + sample(500:1000, 100, replace = TRUE)
)

data <- data %>%
  mutate(
    TimeToEvent = as.numeric(pmin(EventDate, CensorDate) - SwitchDate),
    Status = ifelse(EventDate <= CensorDate, 1, 0)
  )

fit <- survfit( Surv(TimeToEvent, Status) ~ SwitchType , data = data )
ggsurvplot_facet(fit, data, facet.by = "HbA1c", palette = "jco", pval = TRUE)


But the code gives and error
Error in `map()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
ℹ With name: HbA1c.<=7%.
Caused by error in `model.frame.default()`:
! variable lengths differ (found for 'SwitchType')
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
Warning message:
Now, to change color palette, use the argument palette= 'SwitchType' instead of color = 'SwitchType' 


Please provide a random seed for reproducibility.  Have you followed the advice in the warning message?  If so, what happened? Also, try removing the data$ prefixes in your call to Surv.

Random seed is added. data$ is removed. Still there is error
ggsurvplot_facet(fit, data, facet.by = "HbA1c")
Error in combine_vars():
! At least one layer must contain all faceting variables: HbA1c
✖ Plot is missing HbA1c
✖ Layer 1 is missing HbA1c
✖ Layer 2 is missing HbA1c
Run rlang::last_trace() to see where the error occurred.
Warning message:
Now, to change color palette, use the argument palette= 'SwitchType' instead of color = 'SwitchType'

In general, you shouldn't include special characters in your facetting variable (HbA1c) here. I think this is not mentioned in the help page, but it's always good practice to name your variables AND levels of categorical variables appropriately. In this case, the use of = in the levels of the HbA1c variable is causing the error. The function ggsurvplot_facet in the survminer package calls the .get_variables function, which attempts to get the required variables for colouring etc from the strata. The function is:
function (strata, fit, data = NULL) 
{
  variables <- sapply(as.vector(strata), function(x) {
    x <- unlist(strsplit(x, "=|,\\s+", perl = TRUE))  # <- this code
    x[seq(1, length(x), 2)]
  })
  variables <- unique(as.vector(variables))
  variables <- intersect(variables, colnames(.get_data(fit, 
    data)))
  variables
}

The strata are the combined levels of SwitchType and HbA1c separated by ", ". For example, "SwitchType=A to B, HbA1c=<=7%"
would be the first one.
The function then uses ", " or "=" to split.
x <- unlist(strsplit("SwitchType=A to B, HbA1c=<=7%", "=|,\\s+", perl = TRUE))
x[seq(1, length(x), 2)]
[1] "SwitchType" "HbA1c"      "7%"

The result is an extra unwanted item ("7%"), and although this doesn't produce an error, it does produces an error down the track.

Solution: remove the = sign in the levels of HbA1c.
set.seed(42)

data <- data.frame(
  PatientID = 1:100,
  SwitchType = sample(c("A to B", "B to C", "C to D"), 100, replace = TRUE),

# The first level is problematic
# HbA1c = sample(c("<=7%", "7-8%", ">8%"), 100, replace = TRUE),

# Replace `<=7` with `0-7`
  HbA1c = sample(c("0-7%", "7-8%", ">8%"), 100, replace = TRUE),

  SwitchDate = as.Date("2022-01-01") + sample(0:500, 100, replace = TRUE),
  EventDate = as.Date("2022-01-01") + sample(400:900, 100, replace = TRUE),
  CensorDate = as.Date("2022-01-01") + sample(500:1000, 100, replace = TRUE)
)

data <- data %>%
  mutate(
    TimeToEvent = as.numeric(pmin(EventDate, CensorDate) - SwitchDate),
    Status = ifelse(EventDate <= CensorDate, 1, 0)
  )

fit <- survfit( Surv(TimeToEvent, Status) ~ SwitchType , data = data )
ggsurvplot_facet(fit, data, facet.by = "HbA1c", palette = "jco", pval = TRUE)




It's interesting that you left in the greater-than-sign after saying no "special characters" could be used.

Yes, good point @IRTFM. I've edited my answer. Thanks for that. :)
